# How to fix javascript file referencing old version

Tags: javascript, html

My problem is when I edit my previous javascript or css file link to my html file, the function/code that I add are not functioning even I delete the whole code in my js file. The previous code only is functioning.

Comment: can you show your entire code to us?

Comment: what type of function js do you want?

Comment: sample sir..  i have registerfunction.js(08/19/2015) i edit it now (08/20/2015) adding new function  

function updatefile()
{
alert("test");
}

 this function i add is not reading...

simple function is not reading :(...  even i delete the whole code(empty .js file) and save it.. it run the previous code....

Comment: @shiroJacinto plz show to use your entire updatefile method.

Comment: SAMPLE


    function updatefile()
   {
   alert("testing if function is running");
   }


even I delete this function. its runs to the previous date I save. sir when i rename the js file. all the things i have change are functioning. sir I use also wampserver. is wampserver affecting my code?

Comment: `Ctrl + Shift + Del` and delete history and browser cache. Try this, bro

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It might be your `cache` were not deleted ,that's why it still using your previous javascript file.

To fix that:

- Empty your cache
- (*In GoogleChrome* ) Open developer tools( or press <kbd>F12</kbd> ) then You can right click on
  refresh and select `Empty Cache and Hard Reload`

Your updated `javascript` now will be loaded.

---

**[CLEAR GOOGLE CHROME CACHE](http://www.guidingtech.com/1662/clearing-cache-in-google-chrome/)**

**[CLEAR FIREFOX CACHE](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/how-clear-firefox-cache)**

**[CLEAR INTERNET EXPLORER CACHE](https://kb.wisc.edu/page.php?id=15141)**

Comment: sir I using DW CC... the cache of DW is empty... 

sir where i can see the others file that i must delete..? i use DW CC and wamp server...

Comment: what browser are you using? all you have to do is to empty the browser's cache

Answer (score 0):

What server software are you hosting with? Apache? Express/node?

I noticed depending on how I configured something like forever or nodemon to host my express sites, it did not reflect changes when not using grunt. I had to restart them to get them to use the newly changed files.

Did you use a Yeoman generator?